# (Python,Selenium) How to minimize firefox window while running

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver

how to minimize a firefox window by using selenium and python

i tried with

```
    try:
        body=None
        body = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")
        body.send_keys("{%+" "+N}")
        print "entered keys"
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print "item body is not exists" 

    code:2
    ------
    body.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL+Keys.ESCAPE+'D')

    code:3
    ------
    body.send_keys("{%" "n}")
```

Nothing worked for me i want to minimize my firefox window while running or after invoking

or run in invisible mode which has no focus

Answer (score -1):

The following code should help:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
actionChain = ActionChains(driver).key_down(Keys.ALT)
actionChain.send_keys(Keys.SPACE)
actionChain.send_keys("n")
actionChain.perform()
```

Comment: while running this above code it just remaining idle ...can any one please help me how to minimize browser

Comment: @Vikas Neha Ojha, your code doesn't work on IE and FireFox; it's better if you test your code before submitting an answer.